# Changing link color on focus but not on click (either mouse or keyboard click)

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of a link when a user focuses on it by navigation to it using the TAB key.
that's the easy part, as it's done by this:

```
a:focus{ color: red; }
```

the problem is, the link is also colored red when activated, e.g: when a user clicks the "ENTER" key or the left mouse click.

How can I prevent this side effect and keep the coloring only when user focuses on the link using the "TAB" key ?

I tried this:

```
a:focus{ color: red; }
a:active{ color: blue; }
```

(blue is the default color)
it didn't work, what happens is it first turned the link blue but then red in a slit second...

I need this done of every link on my site so I don't want to use any complicated javascript code to do this and hoping to do this in CSS only.

any suggestions ?

edit: I also tried this:

```
a:active:focus{ color: blue; }
```

in order to capture a state in which the element is focused AND active so I can override a "focus" CSS.
it didn't work either.

Comment: You can't do this with CSS. You would need to use JavaScript to detect a click event and then change the color to blue. You can fake it in some browsers by making `a:visited` the same color as `a:active`, but not all.

Comment: some browsers is better than none.
can you please give an example code of faking it with a:visited and a:active ?
do you mean this:
a:focus{ color: red; }
a:active{ color: blue; }
a:visited{ color: blue; }

Comment: Yes. It'll work in Firefox and maybe IE11, but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the order of the rules.

```
a:link
a:visited
a:hover
a:active
a:focus
```

*Focus* has to be the last.
I tried and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :visited pseudo class

```
a:visited{color:blue;}
```

Comment: didn't work either.
the behavior is the same as a:active
it blinks blue then goes red

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in css only.

When you click a link, you give it focus.

You could try a little jquery routine to give all of your links a click handler which immediately blurs the focus away?

```
$(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function() {
        this.blur();
    });
})
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6sujjuvn/

In the fiddle, you can see that after it spawns the new tab/window, your clicked link back on the jsfiddle page no longer has focus

Comment: thanks but when it comes to functionality I actually DO need the focus to stay on the link when clicked/activated...

Comment: In that case it will remain focused and show the `:focus` color that you have set...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
a:active{ color: default; }
```

Comment: tried it now.
doesn't work.
by the way, I also tried:
a:active{ color: inherit; }

Comment: There is no `default` value for `color` property in CSS.